# Retrieving secret value from encyrpted data bag in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am using a ruby block to get the secret value. However, I want to change it in a way so that secret is not stored as node attribute. Otherwise, it can be visible when viewing attributes in Chef.

```
ruby_block 'load_acl_master_token' do
  block do
  secret = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/etc/chef/app_encrypted_data_bag_secret")
  acl_master_token = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("app_consul_secrets", "app_consul_acl_mastertoken", secret)
  node.set['cluster']['acl_master_token'] = acl_master_token['keyval']
  end
  only_if { node['cluster']['acl'] == true }
end

bootstrap_json = Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(node['consul']['config'].to_hash)
rb_bootstrap_hash = JSON.parse(bootstrap_json)

require "active_support/core_ext/hash"

rb_cluster_hash_acl_master_token = rb_bootstrap_hash.deep_merge({ "acl_master_token" => acl_master_token['uuidgen'] } )
```

How can I write the same code in more efficient way?

the code looks like below

```
rb_cluster_hash_acl_master_token = rb_bootstrap_hash.deep_merge({ "acl_master_token" => acl_master_token['uuidgen'] } )
```

And, i get this error

```
NameError
--------- 
No resource, method, or local variable named acl_master_token' for Chef::Recipe "server"' `
```

should i make `acl_master_token['uuidgen']` as `lazy attribute`. If yes, how will it look like??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to use lambda to lazily evaluate an arbitrary variable with Chef.

```
rb_cluster_hash_acl_master_token = lambda { rb_cluster_hash_acl_policy.deep_merge({ "acl_master_token" => acl_master_token['uuidgen'] } ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite the code that currently uses the node attribute to use the data bag instead? Efficiency isn't really an issue, you just need to do that thing you said.

Comment: If I remove `node.set['cluster']['acl_master_token'] = acl_master_token['keyval']` and directly use `acl_master_token['keyval']`  I get compile time error. Please help what to do

Comment: You need to make sure that variable is set in whatever scope you are accessing it from. Without knowing what the code looks like I can't say much.

Comment: the code looks like below `rb_cluster_hash_acl_master_token = rb_cluster_hash_acl_policy.deep_merge({ "acl_master_token" => acl_master_token['uuidgen'] } )`  And, i get this error ` 
  NameError
  ---------
  No resource, method, or local variable named `acl_master_token' for `Chef::Recipe "server"'
 `

Comment: should i make `acl_master_token['uuidgen']` as `lazy attribute`.  If yes, how will it look like??

Comment: Please either pastebin the code or edit it into your question.

Comment: I mean the entire recipe, all of it.

Comment: I have added entire recipe. please check

Comment: So you can't set a variable in a ruby_block and use it outside of the block. See https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for details on why. You probably need to fundamentally rethink your code, but that is out of scope for StackOverflow.